# What is causing crash in android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, androidx

Since recently I see several occurences of the following crash in my app's crashlytics :

> Fragment.java line 960
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint

```
Fatal Exception: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator + 2855(Parcel.java:2855)
       at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable + 2781(Parcel.java:2781)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue + 2684(Parcel.java:2684)
       at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal + 3134(Parcel.java:3134)
       at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray + 2367(Parcel.java:2367)
       at android.os.Parcel.readValue + 2741(Parcel.java:2741)
       at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal + 3053(Parcel.java:3053)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked + 288(BaseBundle.java:288)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel + 232(BaseBundle.java:232)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.putBoolean + 569(BaseBundle.java:569)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint + 960(Fragment.java:960)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem + 121(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:121)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem + 1004(ViewPager.java:1004)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate + 1186(ViewPager.java:1186)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate + 1086(ViewPager.java:1086)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run + 267(ViewPager.java:267)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run + 986(Choreographer.java:986)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks + 764(Choreographer.java:764)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame + 696(Choreographer.java:696)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run + 965(Choreographer.java:965)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7073(ActivityThread.java:7073)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 494(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 965(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

I cannot reproduce the crash.

Does anyone know what could be causing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the crashes were caused by a bug in one of the support compat libraries, `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` or `'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'`

Migrating to `AndroidX` instead solved the problem.

> With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing
> project to AndroidX by selecting Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from
> the menu bar.

For info:

> AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in
> the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names
> changed; class, method, and field names did not change.
>
> AndroidX is a redesigned library to make package names more clear. So
> from now on android hierarchy will be for only android default
> classes, which comes with android operating system and other
> library/dependencies will be part of androidx (makes more sense). So
> from now on all the new development will be updated in androidx.

Original support libaries are no longer supported by Google:

> Version 28.0.0 is the last release of the Support Library.